# How to verify Facebook signedrequest - valid characters and length

Tags: regex, facebook, validation, response, maxlength

I want to be able to verify via RegEx that a SignedRequest which was supposedly returned by Facebook is the right length (under n max characters) and has only valid characters.

Is there a length limit or limited character set which can appear in such a signedrequest?

If you want the bigger context, here it is: I'm using ESAPI to validate all input into the system.  Since a SignedRequest is already validated using the signature I was thinking of not doing any prior validation with ESAPI, but this opens up all kinds of DOS attacks, so at the very least I would like to verify max size, and if possible also character sets.

Was looking for this info but could not find it, if it's easily available somewhere please link to it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no especially defined max length, because the length depends of the amount of info embedded.

> but this opens up all kinds of DOS attacks

Sorry, but that sounds a little paranoid if you ask me.

Comment: and there's no limit on the amount of info that can be put in there?

Comment: as for being paranoid, it's not paranoia at all, if there's no limit I can get a long request which will keep the server busy verifying the authentication forever (even if it'll fail later).  Do that a couple of times, and all threads are now working on never ending requests. Simple enough, no need to work too hard.  Besides, all input is verified at entry and I'd like to keep it that way.

Comment: “Too large” requests should be rejected by the server config already, and as for verifying, calculating a simple SHA-512 hash is not that costly either …